# Spring logs not written in log4j2

Tags: java, spring, log4j, log4j2, apache-commons-logging

I  am new to spring and log4j.I am trying a sample Hello World project with spring framework and using log4j2 library. I have log4j2.xml in my src folder. When i run the application, only my application logs are written in the log file. The spring logs are not written.However i can see them in the console. I have commons logging jar (spring dependency), log4j2 and spring jars in my classpath. Can anyone help me if I am missing any configuration here?

My log4j2  xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration  status="trace" monitorInterval="5">
<Appenders>
<Console name="consoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
</Console>
<File name="fileAppender" fileName="learning.log" append="true">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
</File>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
<Root level="trace">
  <AppenderRef ref="consoleAppender"/>
  <AppenderRef ref="fileAppender"/>
</Root>
</Loggers>  
</configuration>
```

My Code:

```
public class MainApp {
static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) {
  ApplicationContext context = 
         new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

  log.info("Going to create HelloWord Obj");

  HellowWorld obj = (HellowWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");

  obj.getMessage();

  log.info("Exiting the program");
}
}
```

output:

```
main INFO  springExample.MainApp - Going to create HelloWord Obj
main INFO  springExample.MainApp - Exiting the program
```

The spring logs are missing in the output file.

Thanks,
Suma

Answer (score 28):

Since the other answers don't spell it out in the actual answer, the solution is to add the Commons Logging Bridge dependency below to the Maven pom.xml file.

As stated on the [Apache Log4j web page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.1/maven-artifacts.html):

> If existing components use Apache Commons Logging 1.x and you want to
>   have this logging routed to Log4j 2, then add the following but do not
>   remove any Commons Logging 1.x dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

---

See the example below of the effect of adding this dependency in:

### Before:

```
May 11, 2015 8:10:41 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@300ffa5d: startup date [Mon May 11 20:10:41 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
May 11, 2015 8:10:42 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [datapower.xml]
May 11, 2015 8:10:42 PM org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
May 11, 2015 8:10:42 PM org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller createJaxbContextFromContextPath
INFO: Creating JAXBContext with context path [com.datapower.schemas.management]
May 11, 2015 8:10:45 PM org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller createJaxbContextFromContextPath
INFO: Creating JAXBContext with context path [com.datapower.schemas.management]
May 11, 2015 8:10:47 PM org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
```

### After:

```
22:07:21.925 [main] INFO  org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@22eeefeb: startup date [Mon May 11 22:07:21 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
22:07:21.950 [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [datapower.xml]
22:07:22.059 [main] INFO  org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory - Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
22:07:22.068 [main] INFO  org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller - Creating JAXBContext with context path [com.datapower.schemas.management]
22:07:24.446 [main] INFO  org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller - Creating JAXBContext with context path [com.datapower.schemas.management]
22:07:26.554 [main] INFO  org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory - Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
```